# ubuntu disable charging on usb port (while tethering)

Tags: ubuntu, usb

Dell Inspiron 15 3000
Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Hi can I disable charging of my Android phone while it still usb tethers internet to my laptop? Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable charging of connected USB device (phone)](https://superuser.com/questions/1642860/disable-charging-of-connected-usb-device-phone)

Comment: I don’t think you can disable charging in this situation. Only chance is to see if there is a BIOS to disable

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/429097/how-to-disable-usb-charging-of-external-devices-in-windows-7 also this

Comment: thanks it looks like it's pretty hard to do, I'm going to maybe try on the Android level.  I checked my bios and there was no option for it.

Answer (score 2):

A kluge workaround: plug a *powered* USB hub into the laptop, the phone into the hub, and power the hub from an external battery, i.e., USB power bank.

Admittedly, this requires carrying a USB hub and USB power bank with you, and even though powered, the hub may *still* use some of the laptop's battery (though less than to charge the phone).

Another option: connect phone and laptop by Bluetooth. Of course, Bluetooth puts a small additional drain on both devices.

BTW, I was reading of someone's experiment to remove the V++ connection (and ground!) to a USB cable, which destroyed his PC's USB port. Don't try that.